# Creating an array from multiple $.get calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to populate a javascript array that will be used to pass into the Google Visualizations API

I have multiple tables containing simple stock data, and each element of the array will hold some piece of information from one table.  So far, this is how I populate the array

```
function drawMapOfPortfolio(symbols, chart_div) {
var gdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
gdata.addColumn('string', 'Symbol');
gdata.addColumn('string', 'Sector');
gdata.addColumn('number', 'Volume');
gdata.addColumn('number', 'Percent Change');
gdata.addRow(["Portfolio", null, 0, 0]);
gdata.addRow(["Information Technology", "Portfolio", 0, 0]);
gdata.addRow(["Financials", "Portfolio", 0, 0]);
gdata.addRow(["Consumer Staples", "Portfolio", 0, 0]);
gdata.addRow(["Consumer Discretionary", "Portfolio", 0, 0]);

//setup arrays to store the XHR objects to resolve
//and to store the data returned from the server for each request
var jqXHRs = [],
data = [];

//your loop will run faster if you cache the length of the array
for(i=0, len = symbols.length; i < len; i++) {
    //create an IIFE to save the state of the `i` variable for each callback function
    //IIFE = Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression
    (function (i) {
        var symbol = symbols[i];
        jqXHRs[i] = $.ajax({
            url: "mysql_api.php", 
            type: "GET",
            data: { sqlquery: "SELECT volume, day_change_percent, sector FROM " + symbol + " LEFT JOIN sector USING(symbol) ORDER BY unixTS DESC LIMIT 1" },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(serverResponse) {
                var treemapData = [symbol, serverResponse[0]["sector"], parseFloat(serverResponse[0]["volume"]), parseFloat(serverResponse[0]["day_change_percent"])];
                data[i] = treemapData;
            }
        });
    })(i);
}

//when all the XHR objects resolve, add their server responses to your `gdata` object
$.when(jqXHRs).then(function () {
    gdata.addRows(data);
    alert(data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById(chart_div));
    chart.draw(gdata, {
    minColor: '#f00',
    midColor: '#ddd',
    maxColor: '#0d0',
    headerHeight: 15,
    fontColor: 'black',
    showScale: true
    });
});
```

}

but in order to do so, I have to set async to false.  By setting async to true, the queries are sent out and google visualizations tries to draw the chart before the array is populated.  Are there any ways around this?  I think what I am looking for is

Use async $.ajax call to populate the array, but then wait for everything to sync before calling Google Visualization's draw function.

Updated: changed javascript code but "data" array is empty inside $.when

Comment: This is a variation on one of the most frequently asked (non-trivial) JavaScript questions. You'll get a great answer here very soon, I predict :-)

Comment: why are you exposing sql statements in ajax and not just sending symbols to php all at once and doing all the array compiling there

Comment: @charlietfl wow I just noticed that - that's an extremely dangerous thing to do ...

Comment: @Pointy  apart from being a stupid thing to do...would make compiling a lot easier in one call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//setup arrays to store the XHR objects to resolve
//and to store the data returned from the server for each request
var jqXHRs = [],
    data   = [];

//your loop will run faster if you cache the length of the array
for(i=0, len = symbols.length; i < len; i++) {

    //create an IIFE to save the state of the `i` variable for each callback function
    //IIFE = Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression
    (function (i) {
        var symbol = symbols[i];
        jqXHRs[i] = $.ajax({
            url      : "mysql_api.php", 
            type     : "GET",
            data     : { sqlquery: "SELECT volume, day_change_percent, sector FROM " + symbol + " LEFT JOIN sector USING(symbol) ORDER BY unixTS DESC LIMIT 1" },
            dataType : "json",
            success  : function(serverResponse) {
                var treemapData = [symbol, serverResponse[0]["sector"], parseFloat(serverResponse[0]["volume"]), parseFloat(serverResponse[0]["day_change_percent"])];

                //add the server response from this request to the same index as the XHR object for this request
                data[i] = treemapData;
            }
        });
    })(i);
}

//when all the XHR objects resolve, add their server responses to your `gdata` object
$.when(jqXHRs).then(function () {
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        gdata.addRow(data[i]);
    }
});
```

## A Stern Word of Warning

You are passing full SQL queries into your server-side script. This is extremely unsecure as I can just use my developer console to paste in any SQL I want to run. For instance I could delete your whole database very easily...

Comment: Ah I see, even if I set the permissions on that account to only have SELECT ability?

Comment: since the $.ajax calls still use async:false, does that mean I still have to wait for all the queries to be sent individually?

Comment: @JCWong I forgot to remove the `async:false` from the code. Using the above method it is not necessary and all of this can happen without the user knowing.

Comment: Everything makes sense to me so far, but for some reason the "data" array is still not populated when GViz tries to draw.  I moved the drawing code into the $.when.then part.  According to the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ this should only get executed once jqXHRR has finished resolving, and since the success function populates 'data' whenever jqXHR is resolved data should be populated

Comment: @JCWong Make sure you aren't using the same variable name more than once. I changed your original `data` variable to `serverResponse` (inside the AJAX callback function) so that the "global" `data` variable wouldn't get messed-up. In hind-sight that was foolish of me...

Comment: looks like you have to use $.when.apply(this, jqXHRs).then, otherwise $.when doesn't like to take an array of deferreds.  All working now!  Thanks!